# Error while starting batch file with parameters

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I try to launch a batch file from my Java application, but I only get an error window. It says:

```
"1" could not be found. Make sure that you used the right name and
repeat the process
```

(Free translation from german Windows 10). `"1"` is the number I try to give to the batch file.

I try to launch from a directory which contains spaces, e.g.: `C:\user\my stuff\` etc.
Here is the specific code I am using:

```
String[] commands = {"cmd", "/c" , "start", batchfile.toString() , String.valueOf(ParameterNumber)};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

`batchfile` is a valid path written like this: `C:\Users\Admin\directory and stuff\`

`ParameterNumber` is a valid `int` between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `start` is an application title (run `start /?` to see the minihelp). You may use an empty string.

However in this case `start` isn't necessary, simply remove it from `commands`.

Comment: After removing the `start` parameter, it wont even launch an application window of `cmd`. Maybe it is something with my system? Another thing i noticed is that the Windows process `Runtime Broker` uses about 30% of my cpu as soon as i try to start the `process`

Comment: Surround `batchfile.toString()` with explicit doubleqoutes as it has spaces in the path name so `cmd` sees it as two or more different parameters.

Comment: I surrounded `batchfile.toString()` with `"\""` and tested it, but it is still not opening anything. Even after readding `start` it is still showing the error message. I think the problem really is the new `Windows 10`. Maybe you can try it out for yourself and see if it works. Just output the parameter in cmd and see if it works on Windows 8 or 7

Comment: I found a workaround for using no `batch-file`. Problem is not solved maybe someone will find something in the future.